# How to publish a Node but not create a link to it in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I am trying to create a "Node Pointer" document type that allows the content manager to select one or more Nodes not located under the Home Node. This is basically so that they can select which controls to add to a page without having to create a ton of them under the page. My question is, how do I create that "Node Pointer" and publish it without a link to it being created?

Comment: Also, I know that I could just keep from publishing it and retrieve its data from the unpublished document, but I can't guarantee that the content manager will refrain from publishing the entire site at once.

Comment: It would be bad practice to access the unpublished document as it would require calling the database instead of reading the cache. What is the purpose of the "Node Pointer"? What will it do exactly?

Comment: Node Pointer is a child node that allows the content manager to select nodes that are located in a folder/tree OUTSIDE the main site's directory. The point is to eliminate the use of a node picking datatype in EVERY SINGLE document type, yet allow the client to add the child "Node Picker" to whichever pages they desire and it builds controls/content areas automatically, based on the data in the selected nodes. This is more or less to eliminate redundancy in content items (even though the Node Picker itself may be redundant, it still allows access to multiple nodes in one control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links are generated by your template, so you need to include some logic in your template to exclude those pages you don't want links to.

You can do it by checking the docTypes, or excluding items with no temlate, or use a property such as umbracoHaviHide.

Alternatively avoid creating nodes that are not pages, perhaps like so:
We often use a similar technique to create a collection of sidebar elements that are prefabricated outside the home branch, then re-used. 
They are re-used by selecting the desired components via a uComponents MultiNodeTreePicker which is a property on every page that should have selectable sidebar components. This way there are no nodes under the home branch that are not supposed to be pages, hence you don't have to do anything to excluded links to them.

**Edit**
The CMS will give every node a URL, this generally does not matter, because if there is no template associated with the node anyone visiting that url will get the 404 page. Older versions of umbraco will serve a blank page. (pre 4.5? ish? I think?)

Comment: I have done this before, but I don't want to dictate to the client that EVERY SINGLE PAGE/DOCUMENT TYPE has to have that Node Picker in it, however it is seeming like that will be the best approach, unfortunately. Also, what do you mean that I can include logic in my template to exclude those pages I don't want links to?

Comment: Template logic depends on which style of template you use, UserControls/Masterpages? XSLT? or Razor?.... one of these will be rendering your links, perhaps include in your question a snippet of the template that renders the links you don't want.

Comment: Really what I want is the ability to create content items outside the "Home" branch that don't have a link associated with them after I publish them, but are available in the Node picker that I provide to my client in certain doc types. I'm not trying to render the selected nodes on a page or something, I'm using the nodes for their data, using custom functionality to display information on a page. For example, the "About Us" page has a node picker, and that node picker allows the client to select snippets of info to display on the "About Us" page (such as address, email, phone, whatever).

Comment: @ddore95 added extra info to answer

Comment: Thanks @Myster, this is really helpful. I think I'll just deal with the 404 page and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you create a node in the content area, it will always have a url associated. You can either make sure the document type doesn't have a default template, if you don't want it to be navigable, or you can assign it a blank template.

Alternatively, you could create a new media type. Media nodes do not have urls associated to them by default.

Comment: Not sure I follow on the whole new media type. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ddore95, I'm not sure I understand your query completely - I'm assuming you just want to create nodes that you can add to a picker. The nodes should contain content, but should not have a url associated with them. If that is the case, you can create a media type the same way you create a document type. You can add the same properties to a media type that you can to a document type. You can also set the multinode tree picker to choose media nodes. The downside is that the nodes reside in the media section, which would be less desirable.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. That is a brilliant alternative, however I'd rather everything be available to the client in the content tree so that they can see everything in one place. Thanks for your input!